# Portable make clean rule

Tags: makefile, mingw, porting

I am writing a smallish C program for fun. I decided to just use MinGW (only C), make and Notepad++ as an exercise in not using fancy IDEs for a change. So far so good and fun.

(MinGW == I am working on Windows.)

Now since the program compiles against vanilla C I thought of making it fully portable. MinGW make and gcc is smart enough create a program from the rule:

```
myprog: myprog.o other.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

Obviously, since I am on windows the compiler creates `myprog.exe`. This is quite smart and makes the entire thing quite portable.

As far as [standard targets](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Standard-Targets) go I want to at least implement `clean` since I actually use that rule. Now the clean target, that actually works on Windows looks like this:

```
clean:
   rm myprog.exe *.o
```

This rule will definitely not work in a POSIX environment, because programs don't have extensions there.  (PSOIX: think GNU/Linux)

Is there a portable way implement a clean without to much make fu?

So far I have not found any really useful documentation around this issue. If you look at how autoconf and automake tackle the issue, they introduce the pattern `@EXEEXT@`. But that relies on lengthy configure code testing the environment.

Comment: What's wrong with `rm -f myprog myprog.exe *.o`?

Comment: Ever tried to execute that on Linux? Does not work... The question refers to potability; the rule works fine on mingw.

Comment: Yes I have, and it works on my version (2.6.18-194.8.1.el5). What's your error? (And why would you want to drink it?)

Comment: Except that when I generate `myprog`, then trying to delete `myprog.exe` will result in a nice `No such file or directory.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If solved it the following way:

```
UNAME = $(shell uname -o)
ifeq ($(UNAME), Msys)
  EXEEXT = .exe
endif

clean:
    rm *.o myprog$(EXEEXT)
```

It solved the issue quite nicely. Although it is not totally 100% portable it works most common cases.

Answer (score 1):

Define the binary name as a variable (optionally deduce it from the name of the source file defining "main()" with a simple egrep command):

```
EXE_EXT_LINUX:=
EXE_EXT_WINDOWS:=exe
EXE_EXT:=$(EXE_EXT_$(PLATF))

BINARY_NAME:=$(notdir $(basename $(shell egrep -r -l --include=*.cpp '^[ \t]*?int[ \t]*?main[ \t]*?\(') ) )$(EXE_EXT)
```

And use this macro instead of hardcoded name

Comment: I think this is half in the right direction; but I think that this is overkill. (Especially since I actually have two programs...) I think I might go with a test on the result from uname.